# Read-only python shelve to store {key->value} on google-app-engine?

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, shelve

I'm implementing morphology module for my app on google-app-engine. To do this I need a key-value database that stores a lot of small objects. I also need to perform huge amount of queries. So, I consider shelve module to be perfect solution.

Unfortunately, google-app-engine doesn't allow to use any python built-in databases because it doesn't allow to write into local files. However, I don't need writing, but only reading.

Is there any implementation of read-only db that can be run under google-app-engine.

P.S. I don't consider using google app engine datastore for this purpose because of huge amount (but small sized) of stored objects and because of huge abount of queries.

Comment: You shoudl quantify huge. Unless you are willing to pay money, you will be limited to around 120MB of memory, and also consider what your startup time will be.  If you have to read large amounts of data at startup you will potentially have long startups. You can always pickle something, write it to the file system in development. The deploy the pickle file with your code. The you can read it.

Comment: In addition, if you are just using a key value store, how do plan to do queries ?  Iterate over every entity.  By not using the datastore you won't get indexes, unless you build those in memory yourself, which will cost.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a read-only db, then write the data into a file before you deploy your app.  You can read from it with your program on appengine, just like you would read a template file.  Write the data in sorted order and use a binary search to locate the key(s).

Another option is to put the key-value pairs into [memcache](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/functions).  That's very fast and can handle a huge amount of queries.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have already written simple BTree to solve my task. That's because I haven't found existing solution.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @typedef any chance you posted this GAE compatible btree somewhere?